# Coolermaster CM 690 power button problem

Tags: boot, case

The computer was not booting up (no beep), I did almost everything (Taking RAM, Graphics card out, cleaning everything, replacing cmos etc etc).

Power was going to the motherboard as CPU fan was on. There was no main power light (blue) on the CM 690 but the hard disk light was always RED irrespective of whether the disk was connected or not.

It just happened randomly that just moving/pushing the wires on the front panel (3 in count) made the power light blink very fast. I switched off the main power, pushed the wires little bit in and powered back on.

The system booted with no problems at all. After 4-5 hours the system just froze the it wont boot up again. Then I again moved/pushed the wires little bit, powered on and it started.

This has happened couple of times now and I am practically unable to solve this problem. My guess is that maybe the wires have got loose and need a little bit of soldering due to which sometimes there is some electricity short circuit which hangs the system.

Any ideas or advice on this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My CM 690 is running fine... so this is not an inherant problem.

I would start by carefully checking the case connections to the motherboard—it is very easy to get power switch/power led/hard disk led/... connections the wrong way around or mixed up.

Also double check all the PSU connections (motherboard, HDD, ...) including at the PSU end if it is a modular PSU.

---

As that has been checked, and this is not a new system: I would suspect a motherboard fault has developed (or maybe PSU).

Comment: CM 690 is around 2.5 years old, the problem just came up yesterday.
I already removed, cleaned all the components/connections.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem, i was able to remove the power button plug from the mobo, and using a screwdriver to connect the two pins which will boot the machine. I need to perhaps replace or otherwise fix the wires but for now this'll do.